# What should I do with this question?

Tags: support

I posted [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28125/how-should-i-increase-the-range-of-my-wireless-network)
and was informed that it is off topic.  I don't think I have the reputation I need to move a question.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the policy is to only move questions to other Stack Exchanges if there are any answers preserving and this was the case here, I've nominated the question for moving. It's now up to the Super User community to decide if they accept this.